# How to get distinct data from two tables using SQL Select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get distinct data from two tables using SQL Select query. I need to know how many users started innovation but need distinct data. The below following are two tables. Table_UserInformation is basic registration table, after login he can add many innovations but registration only one for one email id.

Table_UserInformation

```
Name      Email             mobile
mazhar    mazar@gmail.com   720000000
rahul     rahul@gmail.com   992000000
raj       raj@gmail.com     700000000
```

Table_Innovation

```
Email             Data1                Data2
mazar@gmail.com   aim to achive LD     NA
mazar@gmail.com   Search for LD        NA
rahul@gmail.com   mind tech            Techno
```

I want to know how many users started innovations counts and details like below 2 outputs need.

1. output: How many users started Innovation base on email need counts.

   ```
   counts
    2
   ```
2. output: How many users started Innovation base on email need details of users.

   ```
    Name      Email             mobile
    mazhar    mazar@gmail.com   720000000
    rahul    rahul@gmail.com   992000000
   ```

Comment: any buddy there for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get using distinct count and exists for these queries

For count:

```
select count(distinct Email) from Table_innovation
```

For distinct users

```
select * from Table_UserInformation t where exists (select 1 from Table_innovation i where i.email = t.email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, this will give you the required output as mentioned by you in question.

```
DECLARE @Table_UserInformation TABLE(Name  varchar(100),    Email         varchar(100),        mobile varchar(100))
DECLARE @Table_Innovation TABLE(Email  varchar(100),    DATA1         varchar(100),        DATA2 varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @Table_UserInformation VALUES
('mazhar',    'mazar@gmail.com',   '720000000'),
('rahul',    'rahul@gmail.com',   '992000000'),
('raj',       'raj@gmail.com',     '700000000')
INSERT INTO @Table_Innovation VALUES
('mazar@gmail.com',   'aim to achive LD',     'NA'),
('mazar@gmail.com',   'Search for LD',        'NA'),
('rahul@gmail.com',   'mind tech',            'Techno')
;WITH SAMPLEDATA
AS
(
SELECT Email,COUNT(EMAIL)COUNTS FROM @Table_Innovation GROUP BY Email
)
SELECT T2.Name,T2.Email,T2.mobile,T1.COUNTS FROM SAMPLEDATA T1 JOIN     @Table_UserInformation T2 
ON T1.Email=T2.Email
```

**OUTPUT**

```
-----------------------------------------
--Name  Email   mobile  COUNTS
-----------------------------------------
mazhar  mazar@gmail.com 720000000   2
rahul   rahul@gmail.com 992000000   1
-----------------------------------------
```

Separate queries for both:

```
SELECT Email,COUNT(EMAIL)COUNTS FROM @Table_Innovation GROUP BY Email

;WITH SAMPLEDATA
AS
(
SELECT Email,COUNT(EMAIL)COUNTS FROM @Table_Innovation GROUP BY Email
)
SELECT T2.Name,T2.Email,T2.mobile FROM SAMPLEDATA T1 JOIN     @Table_UserInformation T2 
ON T1.Email=T2.Email
```

OUTPUT

```
-----------------------
Email   COUNTS
-----------------------
mazar@gmail.com 2
rahul@gmail.com 1

------------------------------------
Name    Email   mobile
------------------------------------
mazhar  mazar@gmail.com 720000000
rahul   rahul@gmail.com 992000000
```

Comment: i need how many started innovaiton counts sepereate query for both. @Gaurav Rajput

Comment: i have edited my answer above, now you have two separate queries and single query to get the result as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
  SELECT  
   a.[Name]
  ,a.[Email]
  ,a.[Mobile]
  ,(select count(b.Email) from Table_Innovation as b where b.Email = a.Email)
    as 'Innovat ion Count'
 FROM Table_UserInformation as a
```

Your Result should like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRkQh.png)

Greetz
K4ckr31z

Comment: please understand what i am asking. @k4ckr31z

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make use of below code for the desire output:

```
    DECLARE @Table_UserInformation TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100),Email VARCHAR(100),mobile VARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO @Table_UserInformation VALUES
    ('mazhar','mazar@gmail.com','720000000'),
    ('rahul','rahul@gmail.com','992000000'),
    ('raj','raj@gmail.com','700000000')

    DECLARE @Table_Innovation TABLE(Email VARCHAR(100),DATA1 VARCHAR(100),DATA2 VARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO @Table_Innovation VALUES
    ('mazar@gmail.com','aim to achive LD','NA'),
    ('mazar@gmail.com','Search for LD','NA'),
    ('rahul@gmail.com','mind tech','Techno')

    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT Email) AS COUNTS 
    FROM 
        @Table_Innovation

    SELECT 
        DISTINCT T1.Name,T1.Email,T1.mobile
    FROM 
        @Table_UserInformation T1  INNER JOIN @Table_Innovation T2 ON T1.Email=T2.Email
```